# Start module pn532 by C++ on Rasberry

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I want to start **pn532**

```
int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB2", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY );
...
char cmd[] = {0x55, 0x55, 0, 0, 0};
do {
n_written = write( USB, &cmd[spot], 1 );
spot += n_written;
} while (cmd[spot-1] != '\r' && n_written > 0);
```

but it not working. Where is my mistake?

Comment: where is `spot` declared and assigned, from which value does it start? what is the error? at a first glance, I'd swap positions of the two conditions in the while loop in case n_written ends up zero.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Note also that `cmd[spot-1]` will never be equal to `\r` (in fact, the compiler may even see that, and eliminate the test entirely!)